# Associate personal VSTS to an Organisation

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-account

When I created VSTS account, mistakenly I have chosen Personal instead of Work,School... (as you can see on the picture)

Now I need to associate it with my organisation account. I search a lot and I couldn't find anything useful.

Please guide me to solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, you can't associate personal VSTS to an Organisation Although both identities use the same email address, they're still separate identities with different profiles, security settings, and permissions.

Please see the Q&A below:

> [Why must I choose between a "work or school account" and my "personal
>   account"?](http://Why%20must%20I%20choose%20between%20a%20%22work%20or%20school%20account%22%20and%20my%20%22personal%20account%22?)
>
> - **Choose Work or school account** if you want to use your organization's    directory to authenticate VSTS users and to control
>     VSTS account    access. This limits access to members in your
>     organization's    directory. All other users must sign in with work or
>     school accounts    too.
> - **Choose Personal account** if you want to use your Microsoft account    with VSTS. All other users must sign in with Microsoft
>     accounts too.

1. If you feel annoying about the pop-up, you could just follow the
   link to rename your personal Microsoft account.
2. If you are worrying about the subscribers：

> Within the Visual Studio subscriber portal, you may be able to add an
>   **alternate identity**--in addition to the identity you used during activation. Today we allow you to add an alternate identity if you
>   used a Microsoft account to activate your subscription. This way you
>   can also add a work or school account (which you use when logging into
>   Visual Studio, Office 365, or your corporate or school network),
>   **allowing you to access VSTS using both your personal account and your work or school account.**

Detail steps please take a look at：[How to add an alternate identity to your Visual Studio subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/vs-alternate-identity?view=vsts)

3. If you can't sign in when choose both please see: [Why can't I sign
   in after I choose either "personal Microsoft account" or "work or
   school account"?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/faq-create-account?view=vsts#q--why-cant-i-sign-in-after-i-choose-either-personal-microsoft-account-or-work-or-school-account)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the information. It was solved by connecting VSTS to Azure active directory.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link to associate your personal account with a organization account.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2018/mar-05-vsts#subscriptions

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was solved just by connecting VSTS to Azure active directory